# How to Make Unique DataStore for each glance widget?

Tags: android, glance-appwidget, glance

While trying to use the WeatherApp Sample, I am not understanding how I would change it so that each widget did infact use it's own datastore, rather than a shared one.

My understanding is that datastore as it is in the sample below, are saved to the DATA_STORE_FILENAME, and thus each widget overwrites the last, so all widgets essentially would have the same state.

The comment says to **create a store using the provided fileKey** but I don't know how I could get the fileKey before creating the datastore?

```
/**
 * Provides our own definition of "Glance state" using Kotlin serialization.
 */
object WeatherInfoStateDefinition : GlanceStateDefinition<WeatherInfo> {

    private const val DATA_STORE_FILENAME = "weatherInfo"

    /**
     * Use the same file name regardless of the widget instance to share data between them
     *
     * If you need different state/data for each instance, create a store using the provided fileKey
     */
    private val Context.datastore by dataStore(DATA_STORE_FILENAME, WeatherInfoSerializer)

    override suspend fun getDataStore(context: Context, fileKey: String): DataStore<WeatherInfo> {
        return context.datastore
    }

    override fun getLocation(context: Context, fileKey: String): File {
        return context.dataStoreFile(fileKey)
    }
```

My best guess was to replace all instances of DATA_STORE_FILENAME with the fileKey, but for the creation of the datastore, it does not work, as the key has not yet been created?

`private val Context.datastore by dataStore(fileKey, WeatherInfoSerializer)`

Could someone please provide some clues as to how the fileKey is supposed to be used to create a unique datastore per widget?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get help from the Kotlin slack group which has a Glance channel. The change below is quite simple and is able to be added directly to the example WeatherApp and only changes a line or two in the worker (so that each widget displays different information for testing purposes).

```
// Rename DATA_STORE_FILENAME for clarity
 private const val DATA_STORE_FILENAME_PREFIX = "weatherInfo_"

// The below line can be removed as it is no longer needed
//private val Context.datastore by dataStore(DATA_STORE_FILENAME, WeatherInfoSerializer)


// getDataStore now uses DataStoreFactory
    override suspend fun getDataStore(context: Context, fileKey: String) = DataStoreFactory.create(
        serializer = WeatherInfoSerializer,
        produceFile = { getLocation(context, fileKey) }
    )

    override fun getLocation(context: Context, fileKey: String) =
        context.dataStoreFile(DATA_STORE_FILENAME_PREFIX + fileKey.lowercase())
```

And that's it. Now data store in the example WeatherApp will create a file per widget.